# VSCode cannot treat TS file type informations which imported by a short path

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

```
import MyClass form '@/MyClass'
```

Where `MyClass.ts` is in `/User/my/workspace/src/` and `@` is a shorthand of `/User/my/workspace/src/` in vue-cli 3.0 generated project.

```
import MyClass from './MyClass'
```

was worked fine.

I think VSCode can't treat '@' in the path, but '@' is a good practice instead of using relative path when the path is long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many folders in my VSCode workspace inspector, and VSCode may only use the first folder's `tsconfig.json`. If your `tsconfig.json` is not in the first folder, drag the folder to the first and try it again, it worked for me.